# How to level up fast with the 2015 Compendium c.q. is there any connection between coins and leveling?

Tags: dota-2

I've bought the "The International Five Compendium" for my friends and me, as there is a special thing where you will get more coins if there are five compendium owners in your team as well as a greater chance to level up. However, I'm not getting any points to level up; it feels ultra rare to get points. Are there any other ways how to level up?

Especially, is there any way that we can level up faster with a team?

Comment: Votedown can have many causes: Formatting of the question (which yours is lacking), not clear what the question really is, more than one question, etc.

Comment: @Leothelion I've edited your question now, please don't include your ideas in questions. (And do not hate Dota/Valve).

Comment: @Ardaozkal ok sir i won't hate Dota/valve but if they will use these types of polices then what should we do? spending dollars on the games but not saying anything? right?

Comment: @Leothelion I think just like you, it is stupid to spend 10$ and then spend 3$ for every 5 level. But Arqade is a neutral website, you can't support nor say that they are doing something wrong in a question/answer, but you can say your personal comment in this part, the comments. Let's keep our personal (not that personal on this case actually) idea off the question, ok?

Comment: ok ardaozkai..i won't say any word..:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now there simply isn't any other way.

Last year's compendium had a few ways of leveling up your compendium through daily hero challenges and what not.

The community has launched somewhat of an outcry towards Valve in hopes of having a few ways of leveling up your compendium that doesn't include spending more money.

Give it a few days and you might see more ways of increasing your compendium level.

Edit: 15/5 -15

Compendium Additions

Added a fourth Challenge, which is always a Hero specific Challenge, and rewards completion with both Compendium Coins & Points.

Challenges are now available in Captains Mode, Captains Draft, Random Draft, Single Draft, and All Random game modes.

Ten Hero Challenge added to compendium, also enabled on the above mentioned modes. This year you can do the Ten Hero challenge 3 times for a total of 450 Compendium Points (4.5 Levels).

You can now destroy an Immortal to gain 200 Compendium Points for each.

Added back the Item Recycling system. You can now recycle 10 items for a Charm of the Crucible Jewel II and 25 Compendium points.

Added 3 Recycle Charm Achievements. Create 1 Charm, Create 10 Charms, and Open 8 Charms. Worth 50, 125, and 200 points respectively.

Added All-Star match voting (provides 50 Compendium Points).

Comment: @ Dennis i also bought last year compendium and that time it was easy to get point like 3 4 times in day..but this time not me even my friends..they are getting coins but not the points and by coins we are only getting cheap items so its like..:( and if i will go through other way then only 10 level up but what about 175 means you must have to buy..:(

Comment: Yeah, I hear you. I have played 20 or so games since I obtained my compendium and only had one drop of 25 coins. And the coins do not even relate to xp, but to item / set drop. There are things you can look up in the compendium that will earn you some experience such as predicting the TI5 invites that will close in a day or two.

Comment: you will get only 25 xp..and if i will go through book then only way is to get correct predict of winning team..but its like impossible..:) but anyway..if you get any way then please let me know..thanx..:)

Comment: Yea it is really weird, for once I feel that the community has some merit in one of their outcries :) I will try to remember to update this should Valve implement something new in the days to come.